# how to get a dictionary of first and last from a list of string 'first last' in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-science

I have this list of string:

```
lst = ['vikas mahajan','Rahul shah' , 'xyz abc']
```

desired output:

```
dct = {'first':['vikas' 'Rahul' 'xyz'],'last':['mahajan','shah','abc']}
```

can the solution be a single line of code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict`/`zip`/`str.split`:

```
lst = ['vikas mahajan','Rahul shah', 'xyz abc']

dict(zip(('first', 'last'), list(zip(*(e.split(maxsplit=1) for e in lst)))))
```

Output:

```
{'first': ('vikas', 'Rahul', 'xyz'), 'last': ('mahajan', 'shah', 'abc')}
```

Or as a dictionary comprehension:

```
{k: list(v) for k,v in zip(('first','last'), zip(*(e.split(maxsplit=1) for e in lst)))}
```

Output:

```
{'first': ['vikas', 'Rahul', 'xyz'], 'last': ['mahajan', 'shah', 'abc']}
```